# Derived from template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use the following code, but can't get it to complete.

Can anyone see the problem?

```
class IResourceJob
{
public:
   virtual ~IResourceJob() {}

   virtual void execute() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class ResourceJob : public IResourceJob
{
public:
   void execute()
   {
      static_assert(false, "Specialised ResourceJob<T> not defined!");
   }
};

template<>
class ResourceJob<int>
{
public:
   void execute()
   {
       // test.
   }
};
```

The following usage gives a compile error:

```
IResourceJob* job = new ResourceJob<int>;
```

Thanks!

Comment: you explicit specialization `ResourceJob<int>` doesn't inherits from `IResourceJob` , also that static cast is wrong, did you mean `static_assert` ?

Comment: Thanks, sorry - the static_cast was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler gives an error for any template that can never be instantiated. For your member function of the class template (i assume you mean `static_assert`), that is true, so the compiler is in right to give you a diagnostic.

You want to make the condition depend on `T` and cleverly make it always evaluate to false *when instantiated*. For example like

```
template<typename T>
struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
class ResourceJob : public IResourceJob
{
public:
   void execute()
   {
      static_assert(always_false<T>::value, 
        "Specialised ResourceJob<T> not defined!");
   }
};
```

Since the compiler cannot know whether the user will put a specialization of `always_false` (which you won't, of course), it cannot early-reject the template anymore.

I also doubt that you wanted to put the static_assert into `execute`, since your error message indicates that `ResourceJob` as a whole needs to be specialized. So put the `static_assert` outside of the member function into the class body. If you *don't* want the user to specialize the whole template, but only the member function, the user instead needs to say

```
// either "inline" and in the header, or not "inline" and in the .cpp file, but then 
// put this into the header: template<> void ResourceJob<int>::execute();
template<> inline void ResourceJob<int>::execute() {

}
```

This will provide an alternative definition of `execute` which will be used by the template if `T` is `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
IResourceJob* job = new ResourceJob<int>;
```

fails because the class `ResourceJob<int>` is not derived from from `IResourceJob`.

The code should be

```
template<>
class ResourceJob<int> : public IResourceJob
{
     public:
     void execute()
     {
         // test.
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to derive the template specialization as well, as in:

```
template<>
class ResourceJob<int> : public IResourceJob
{ /* ... */ };
```